# FC persistentvolume: What is the LUN number?

Tags: storage-area-network, fibre-channel, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I'm trying to understand how to use fibre channel with OpenShift/Kubernetes persistent volumes.

At https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_fibre_channel.html#provisioning-fibre it states that target WWN(s) must be specified, along with a LUN number.

I know WWNs, as these are readily availble in the SAN storage system and in operating systems (eg in output from "multipath -ll" on Linux). But I don't know how to find out which LUN number to write.

Apart from me not knowing where to get the LUN number from, I don't understand what Kubernetes needs that information for (I would like to try to understand that, too).

Answer (score 0):

I am doing some test for openshsift persistent storage using FC.
Now I have Openshift nodes on Ovirt attached with disk via direct LUN, from the nodes I can see the wwn id using lsscsi command.
Unfortunately when to assign storage for the pods, errors did happen

"failed for volume "kubernetes.io/fc/7ee809dd-1da9-11e7-b7ff-001a4a160156-pv0001" (spec.Name: "pv0001") pod "7ee809dd-1da9-11e7-b7ff-001a4a160156" (UID: "7ee809dd-1da9-11e7-b7ff-001a4a160156") with: no fc disk found"

Or perhaps this approach via direct LUN / RDM is not supported.